# Problems with an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing a login for a page, if I enter index.html it has to redirect me to the login, html.
the issue here is that I am getting an infinite loop and I don't know what my syntax error is, I would appreciate your help!

**This is where the error is:**

```
sessionStorage.setItem('usuario',false)
var usuario = sessionStorage.getItem(usuario)
var logueate = window.location.replace('login.html')
 if (!sessionStorage.getItem('usuario')) {
 logueate;}
```

**my login JS code**

```
 function validacion(){
      var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
      var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
            
      if (email == "" )  {
        document.getElementById("errores").innerHTML = "Campos invalidos";
      }  else if (password == "") {
        document.getElementById("errores").innerHTML = "Campos invalidos";
      } 
       else { window.location.href="index.html"
```

Answer (score 1):

Does your login.html is alos executing this code, if yes then it is redirecting again and again to login.html page.